# Iframe jquery event handlers not firing when redirected from parent frame

Tags: c#, jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

Our solution runs with a parent frame and a main content iframe. One of the pages in the main content iframe is set up with a series of divs used as tabs, example as follows.

```
<div id="topRow">
    <div class="mainInformation tab tabSelected" runat="server" id="mainInformationTop">
        <div class="tabLeft">
            <div class="tabMain">
                Main Information
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="executives tab" runat="server" id="executivesTop">
        <div class="tabLeft">
            <div class="tabMain">
                Executives
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                
</div
<div id="secondRow">
    <div id="mainInformationTabGroup" runat="server" class="mainInformation tabGroup">
        <div id="overview" runat="server" class="tab tabSelected overview">
            <div class="tabLeft">
                <div class="tabMain">
                    Overview
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="locations" runat="server" class="tab locations">
            <div class="tabLeft">
                <div class="tabMain">
                    Locations
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="executivesTabGroup" runat="server" class="executives tabGroup" style="display: none">
        <div id="companyExecutives" runat="server" class="tab companyExecutives">
            <div class="tabLeft">
                <div class="tabMain">
                    Company Executives
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="affiliatedExecutives" runat="server" class="tab affiliatedExecutives">
            <div class="tabLeft">
                <div class="tabMain">
                    Affiliated Company Executives
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

The jquery event handlers are loaded from a local .js file, example pertaining to the above HTML as follows

```
$('#topRow div.tab').click(function() {
    $('#topRow div.tabSelected').removeClass('tabSelected');
    $(this).addClass('tabSelected');
})
$('#topRow .mainInformation').click(function() {
    $('#secondRow').css('display', 'block');
    $('#thirdRow').css('display', 'none');
    resizeAllIframes();
    $('#secondRow .tabGroup').css('display', 'none');
    $('#secondRow .mainInformation').css('display', 'block');
    $('#secondRow .mainInformation div.tab').not('.locked').children().first().trigger('click');
});
$('#topRow .executives').click(function(){
    $('#secondRow').css('display', 'block');
    $('#thirdRow').css('display', 'none');
    resizeAllIframes();
    $('#secondRow .tabGroup').css('display', 'none');
    $('#secondRow .executives').css('display', 'block');
    $('#secondRow .executives div.tab').not('.locked').children().first().trigger('click');
});
```

(The click events just change the "src" attribute of the iframe)

The issue I'm experiencing is that sometimes when we load this tab page (and only in Internet Explorer 9+, IE7 seems to not have this issue), I'll click on a tab and nothing will happen. The hover events for the CSS are loaded just fine, but click on the tab does nothing. However, if I click one tab and nothing happens, I can click on the next and it will work fine. Similarly, if I click anywhere in the main content frame first and then on a tab, it will always fire the event handler.

We've noticed this problem happening almost entirely when we try to direct to the tabbed page from the parent frame (we have a quicksearch up there) and we use a Response.Redirect to load the iframe with the tab page. I've tried redirecting this quicksearch to a landing page inside the iframe that then uses a Response.Redirect to get us to the tab page, but it ends up with the same results. When we're clicking on a hyperlink from inside the iframe (Target="_self"), that works just fine.

This issue doesn't happen in Firefox, Chrome, or IE7, but it does in IE9+.

Does anybody have any thoughts, ideas, known bugs that I'm missing, anything like that?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: It's 1.4.2 - Painfully out of date, but we're stuck with it for the time being.

Comment: it's weird but I'm guessing it has to do something with that! but I'm afraid I've never seen such a problem! :-s

Comment: I'm concerned that's the issue as well. It's a head-scratcher, that's for sure!

Comment: try binding the click events to the elements and see if it fixes it!

Comment: That's one of those things I'm having trouble doing. The click handlers aren't named functions, but rather when a class in a div is clicked, run that function. I'm not sure how I'd bind that without the explicit function name. This just speaks to my lack of jq/js knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you bind an event to an element:

```
$(document).bind('click','#topRow div.tab',function() {
    $('#topRow div.tabSelected').removeClass('tabSelected');
    $(this).addClass('tabSelected');
});
```

do the exact same for the other events just change the selector part (I mean "`#topRow div.tab`") with the desired selectors.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a go. My concern is what I mentioned in the original post, that the events are generally fine except for that case where we Response.Redirect() the iframe, and they don't work until you've clicked somewhere else inside the iframe. Let me see if the explicit binding helps.

Comment: Well, after trying some explicit binds in both the external .js file and actually putting the functions into the Tab page itself, the problem still exists. We're going to explore upgrading our jQuery, maybe we just need to get up to speed better.